# Merge some parts of a split tar.gz file Linux command

Tags: linux

I have a large tar.gz file (approximately 63 GB) on a linux server. This file has about 1000 compressed csv files. I need to save the data of csv files in a database.

I can't extract whole file in one go due to limited space on the server. So I split the tar.gz file into 5 parts (4 parts of 15 GB and 1 of 3GB) but did not merge all of them as the server won't have any space left when extraction would be done. I merged the first two parts to make a new tar.gz file and extracted the csv files from that.

When I tried to merge the last 3 parts, it did not make a valid tar.gz file and that file could not be extracted. This problem was not because of server space because I deleted the files that were no longer required after extraction from first two parts.

Is there any way through which the last 3 parts of the split tar.gz file can be merged in a valid tar.gz format and then extracted?

**Command used to split :**

```
split -b 15G file.tar.gz parts
```

**Command used to merge :**

```
cat parts* > combined.tar.gz
```

**Command used to extract :**

```
tar zxvf file.tar.gz -C folderwhereextracted
```

Comment: Is recreating the original tar file a different way an option, or are you limited to working with the existing 63 GB file?

Comment: No. I have to work with the 63 GB file only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use short shell script:

```
#/bin/sh

path='./path'
list="$path/*.tar.gz"
for file in `ls ./da/*.tar.gz.*`
    do
        let i++

        if [[ -f $(find $path/*.tar.gz.$i) ]]
            then
                echo "file $path/*.tar.gz.$i found."
                list="$list $path/*.tar.gz.$i"
            else
                echo "file $path/*.tar.gz.$i not found!"
        fi
    done
cat $list > full.tar.gz
tar zxvf ./full.tar.gz -C $path
# rm -rf $list
```

Put your path to variable with the same name.
Uncomment last line to remove source files after untar.